How to point apache to display a local url rather than htdocs root directory
my subdomain name is poiting to my vps windows server, using xampp as a web server, apache and mysql.
I have generated an ssl locally for the apache server and made the vhost point to the subdomain and display the wordpress homepage directly.
But since my wordpress plugin is creating a few errors with xmlrpc and magick I have decided to use a root directory without wordpress located directly on the main windows desktop screen.
The webpage now displays on port 8002, so my new url is now "domain.com:8002/foldername"
how to use the "domain.com" only instead of it ?
Thank you
I have tried editing the vhost inside the extra folder in the apache but I can't seem to make it work.

Question is what you want as a setup. Usually one wants to configure the vhost DocumentRoot such that it points to whatever local folder you want to use as a root for your web content. Using the personal "Desktop" folder is highly unusual, though. You should keep in mind that the http server is a system service, while your desktop is part of your personal section of the file system. Although MS-Windows is not a real multi user system it does make sense to obey the most fundamental rules of data separation.

The second question is where the port number 8002 actually comes from. That suggests that you are not using your local http server, but something else, or a second server in parallel. Is that really what you want? It is unusual, keep in mind that you need to maintain that setup. The less complex the easier that task. Operating two http servers in parallel is unusual and against the idea of such a service.
